# How to solve Google cache displaying links to other websites

Tags: seo, google, blackhat

Google's cache is mine, but the cached page link is somebody else's when I   view Google's cache
My website http://www.hldressbandage.com/
[image]

[image]

I've been unable to solve this, does anyone else know?

Comment: You mean you see other websites when you view the cached version of some of your pages?

Comment: Sounds like you may of been hacked with a script that injects other links when Google bot visits. Due to the lack of information we are unable to assist you further, as we would need to see screenshots and possibly access to the URL to assist you further.

Comment: Google provides resources on recovering from a hacked site: https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598104?hl=en&ref_topic=4598410

You should also have GWT verified and check "Security Issues" section.